# Determining quadratic function of this word problem

Tags: functions, functional-equations, quadratics

I have this word problem in my homework:

```
A tour company offers back country hiking excursions at $160 per person for
groups up to 50. For groups larger than 50, the company will reduce the cost of 
every ticket by $2 for each person in excess of 50. What size of group would
produce the greatest revenue?
```

I'm not worried about finding out what the size of the group is that produces the greatest revenue. What I want to know is what the equation for this is. I was able to figure out this equation:

$$f(x) \ = \ 160x - 2(x-50) \ , $$

where $ \ x \ $ is the number of people and $ \ f(x) \ $ is the revenue. But that's a linear function and we're doing quadratic functions. So, There should be an exponent and I'm thinking there's more to this question than I see? Or is it a linear function?

Comment: You can look at this as combining two simpler functions.  One is to simply have a cost of $160 per person for _any_ group, which produces the term $ \ 160 x \ $ .  The other function is the amount the total revenue is reduced for the "volume discount".  The price reduction _per person_ is $ \ 2 \ (x-50) \ , $ but that is what is being charged _to each person_ in the entire group.  So the _revenue_ reduction is $ \ [ \ 2 \ (x-50) \ ] \ \cdot \ x \ . $  Your second term then needs a further factor of $ \ x \ . $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if you have $n > 50$ people, your revenue will be ticket price for each person (which is $160-2(n-50)$) times the number of people $n$, i.e. $(160-2(n-50))n$.